# Conditional new column with other columns value

Tags: python, pandas

How do you loop through a dataframe and create a new column with other columns value if they are empty or does not fit the condition. What basically want to create is a if statement where PM No_ is empty then select No_ and clean it for all the unwanted characters. I have tried this.

```py
    result_list=[] 
    for i, row in df.iterrows():
    if(df['PM No_'].iloc[i]!=''):
        if df['Condition'].iloc[i] == '9':
           result = df['No_'].str.split('-0G',expand=True)[0]
           result_list.append(result)
    else:
        result=(row['PM No_']) 
        result_list.append(result)
    df['test']=result_list
```

Here is what I want it to look like. That if PM No_ is empty then take No_ instead and if Condition is 9 then remove -0G from No_ when it's added to the new column. I also have some other condition like if Condition is 1 then remove -0S from No_.

| PM No_ | Condition | No_ | test |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| GVSU10K20H | 1 | GVSU10K20H | GVSU10K20H |
| 1Y002VMH | 5 | 1Y002VMH-0H | 1Y002VMH-0H |
|  | 9 | 2NX00ESRU-0G | 2NX00ESRU |
| 20WNGE | 2 | 20WNGE | 20WNGE |
|  | 1 | C33761-0S | C33761 |

Comment: `1Y002VMH-0H` should be `1Y002VMH` according to your logic

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming empty cells are NaNs, use [`fillna`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.Series.fillna.html), [`mask`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.Series.mask.html), [`str.replace`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.Series.str.replace.html):

```
df['test'] = df['PM No_'].fillna(df['No_']
                                 .mask(df['Condition'].eq(9),
                                       df['No_'].str.replace('-0G$', '',
                                                             regex=True))
                                )
```

Output:

```
       PM No_  Condition           No_        test
0  GVSU10K20H          1    GVSU10K20H  GVSU10K20H
1    1Y002VMH          5   1Y002VMH-0H    1Y002VMH
2         NaN          9  2NX00ESRU-0G   2NX00ESRU
3      20WNGE          2        20WNGE      20WNGE
4         NaN          1     C33761-0S   C33761-0S
```

If you have empty strings:

```
df['test'] = (df['PM No_']
              .mask(df['PM No_'].eq(''),
                    df['No_'].mask(df['Condition'].eq(9),
                                   df['No_'].str.replace('-0G$', '',
                                                         regex=True))
                    )
             )
```

Output:

```
       PM No_  Condition           No_        test
0  GVSU10K20H          1    GVSU10K20H  GVSU10K20H
1    1Y002VMH          5   1Y002VMH-0H    1Y002VMH
2                      9  2NX00ESRU-0G   2NX00ESRU
3      20WNGE          2        20WNGE      20WNGE
4                      1     C33761-0S   C33761-0S
```

##### multiple conditions

If you have multiple conditions, as string operations are not easily vectorized, use a loop, here with a custom function

```
def clean(no, condition):
    out = []
    for n, c in zip(no, condition):
        if c == 1:
            n = n.removesuffix('-0S')
        elif c == 9:
            n = n.removesuffix('-0G')
        out.append(n)
    return pd.Series(out, index=no.index)

df['test'] = df['PM No_'].mask(df['PM No_'].eq(''), clean(df['No_'], df['Condition']))
```

Or if all the operations consist in removing a suffix:

```
def clean(no, condition):
    suffixes = {1: '-0S', 9: '-0G'}
    return pd.Series([n.removesuffix(suffixes.get(c, ''))
                      for n, c in zip(no, condition)],
                     index=no.index)

df['test'] = df['PM No_'].mask(df['PM No_'].eq(''), clean(df['No_'], df['Condition']))
```

Output:

```
       PM No_  Condition           No_        test
0  GVSU10K20H          1    GVSU10K20H  GVSU10K20H
1    1Y002VMH          5   1Y002VMH-0H    1Y002VMH
2                      9  2NX00ESRU-0G   2NX00ESRU
3      20WNGE          2        20WNGE      20WNGE
4                      1     C33761-0S      C33761
```

Comment: Does removesuffix only remove when it's in the ending or does it also remove if it's in the middle like this C33761-0S-04

Comment: @Asscha197 `removesuffix` only removes the exact substring from the end of the string if it exists. For example `'ABCAA'.removesuffix('A')` -> `'ABCA'`.